# I am getting similar error in all the program while running the in octave

Tags: octave

```
function plotData(X, y)
%PLOTDATA Plots the data points X and y into a new figure 
%   PLOTDATA(x,y) plots the data points with + for the positive examples
%   and o for the negative examples. X is assumed to be a Mx2 matrix.

% Create New Figure
figure; hold on;

% Find Indices of Positive and Negative Examples
pos = find(y == 1); 
neg = find(y == 0);

% Plot Examples

plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), 'k+','LineWidth', 2, ...
'MarkerSize', 7);
plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'y', ...
'MarkerSize', 7);

hold off;

end
```

**RESULT**

```
octave:17> plotData ()
error: 'y' undefined near line 10 column 12
error: called from
    plotData at line 10 column 5
```

Comment: That’s because you didn’t define `y`. You need to give it a value for your function to run.

Comment: `plotData ()` <== You have to pass `X` and `y` to the function when you call it. See https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Calling-Functions.html